# Laravel uploaded files, low permissions

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, laravel, permissions

Good day everyone.

I am building a Laravel 4 application and I have some file permissions issues.

Once the file has been uploaded by the client, it's moved in a folder. However, the file gets very little permissions, is assigned the user www-data and can't be touched / moved by anything else.

I need to know how to dynamically permit laravel to have permissions on those files because I'm using [CloudConvert](http://cloudconvert.org) to convert this file.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 also and my prod is on debian. I already tried to chmod -R the folder, which works for files already saved, but when new ones are created, it doesn't work anymore and stays in www-data ready-only low permissions.

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT : I might have found something : chmod g+s with given permissions. I read it gave recursive permissions to created files. I'll try once I'm home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake on my side, I'm afraid.

I was renaming the file before curl could pass on it, making it unable to know what was the original file name (getClientOriginalName()).

Answer (score 0):

That account "www-data" is the default account for the web server.  That is why it becomes the owner of the files and has full access to them, from a web angle.  If what is happening is that you are trying to then convert the files outside the web context (like a cron job or something) then you need to make sure the same user (or maybe a group) owns the files.  Have not tried CloudConvert (looks cool, will check it out) but maybe you can leverage Laravel's queues and that way execute your conversion with the web server's "www-data" account?

Comment: Yeah, what happens is that CloudConvert uses CURL to send the file to their servers. I wouldn't know, however, how to give it access to www-data ..

Comment: But it is triggered by a process from the web server?  If so, it should run as www-data and own the files?  Are you storing the uploaded files under the /storage directory?  Since the web server owns that directory the files under there should be accessible.  I have an app that does uploads.  I store the temporary files in a subfolder under app/storage and then I crop, resize, and run an process to upload to AWS S3. Had better luck there than trying under a directory in public since I wanted to just hold them temporarily until they got re-uploaded.

Comment: It gets uploaded inside my public/uploads, folder I created (althought I tried making php create it, without success). Maybe I could store it in the storage folder instead, as it is temporary. Can you help me with a snippet on moving the temporary file ? Thanks :)

Comment: Here is a short snippet of the part in my code that gets the file, calculates a hash for naming it and storing it, checks for the directory to exist, and then moves it (http://laravel.io/bin/DPobW).

Comment: Here is a good blog post that I used to get started when I was first experimenting with these kinds of uploads (http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/uploading-files-in-laravel-4/).

Comment: I answered my own question. It wasn't any permission problem, I'm afraid. Althought, you helped me a lot with uploading files (I used the laravel helper to put the file in my storage). Thanks a lot !